# Strange behavior when closing a workbook twice

Tags: excel, vba

Strange issue when closing a workbook twice from VBA (Workbook_BeforeClose)

Hi. This problem appears to me in an extremely simple workbook: Workbook_BeforeClose only.

```
Option Explicit
     Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

If I open and close the workbook twice, the main Excel screen looks like this, and it's impossible to do something, I can only close it from the status bar:

[image: final status]

Comment: So, you closed the workbook and the application itself still exists.

Comment: What's the aim of this code?

Comment: Last line try `Application.Quit`. I've noticed behavior in a similar situation before as well. I believe it had something to do with other hidden "workbooks" being open, such as a personal macro workbook that can be seen in the VBE. I noticed this behavior was eliminated by looping all workbooks in the application object and ensuring they were closed, so there's another method you can try.

Comment: Tim Williams, obviously is a extreme simplification

Comment: K. Davis, I can't close the entire application, users would kill me :)

Comment: How do you open this Application? Hopefully not with a `Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application`. Instancing the variable within the declare statement can cause results similar to this, making it difficult to destroy the object.

Comment: K Davis There are no other open workbooks, and the code is what you can see. Not one more line. Extremely simple.
the WorkBook is opened as a normal workbook: "File -> Open.

Try to reproduce it. It's simple.

Comment: Are you just wanting to not prompt the user to save changes?

Comment: Exactly: it is a program that should not be saved, for technical reasons of my company. I know that the best solution would be Application.quit, but I can't do it, users can have several books open at once

Comment: Why not just mark the file as read-only?

Comment: Tim Williams, sincerely thank you very much for your interest. K. Davis already answered me. I consider the thread closed. Again, thank you very much for your kindness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is to not prompt the user to save changes, just play with the appropriate flags to 'trick' Excel that changes have already been saved.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Me.Saved = True

End Sub
```

This will allow the workbook to close, without prompting any changes to be saved, but this does *not* actually save them.

Notice the subtle difference between the words: `Me.Saved` and `Me.Save`.

- `Saved` is a **property** that gets flipped to `False` when Excel detects changes were made as of the last save.
- `Save` is a **method** - not a property as above - that actually will save the workbook.

Your workbook *is already closing*, which is what fired this event to begin with. No need to try to close it again within this event. Just tell Excel that no changes have been made since the last save, and it should close all on it's own - without the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're re-triggering the event.  Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Static InProgress As Boolean

     If InProgress Then Exit Sub

     InProgress = True
     ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

I already tried with a static not to happen twice, the result is the same.

The problem is that I can't spill the application, users would kill me :)